# How to get meta data information about the task metadata in AWS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, docker

I want to get the meta data information from the task which runs the docker container in AWS. As per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v2.html), I can hit `http://169.254.170.2/v2/metadata` end point from a container to fetch the info but I am getting `bad request` exception. Please guide me. Below is my attempt.

```
 try
{
    string endpointUrl = "http://169.254.170.2/v2/metadata";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUrl);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var metadata = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(metadata);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex?.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex?.InnerException?.Message);
}
```

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: just to make sure the endpoint is working as expected, do you get a response if you curl the endpoint